# Typescript support for vue files conflicts with Vetur plugin

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

The official vue [docs and github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/sfc.d.ts) suggest that you enable .vue file extension support in Typescript by including this sfc.d.ts file:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

But this seems to conflict with the Vetur plugin. In my `.vue` components, the path / file checking for imports is completely disabled when I use the sfc.d.ts file! Also, changes in .vue files are not reflected in autocomplete anymore.

**index.ts**

```
// only works WITH the sfc.d.ts file
import App from './components/app.vue'
```

**app.vue**

```
<template></template>
<script lang="ts">
    // import only works WITHOUT the sfc.d.ts file!
    import Card from "./card.vue"  
</script>
```

Is this a glitch in Vetur? How do I enable .vue file type in typescript without messing up the single-file-component code completion?

Comment: I have this same setup as far as I can tell, but my imports do work.  I have the Path Intellisense plugin installed though so that may make a difference.  I have noticed the intellisense for vue components is a bit flaky in that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Also, is your code wrapped in `export default Vue.extend({})`? That is supposed to help with intellisense from what I understand.

Comment: That's what's driving me mad! I DO have path intellisense, and that plugin tells me that the module IS there when I start typing a path. But then, when I go to the next line, intellisense is switched off again for both the paths and the code inside .vue files. For example I get no error for `import Nonsense from './nothing/nonsense.vue`

Comment: Have you restarted VSCode and updated to the latest version (came out yesterday I think)?

Comment: @vue/cli (v3+) solves this problem out of the box